# How to append data on a select tag through ajax in Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-mvc

I am making a small Spring MVC Project and I save User data.In the page, when I click on edit the Country data fill from Backend and I apply Ajax Onchange event.

When admin select Country, State list append and when Admin select state, district list append and so on. But when I click on Edit the country data and No state, district data append. I also try to run Ajax on load. Can anyone help me?

My code looks like this:

**UserController.java**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editApplicant/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap) {
    UserDataPojo userDataPojo = userDataService.getDetailsById(id);
    List<DestinationPojo> destinationPojos = destinationService.getAllCountries();

    modelMap.addAttribute("countries", destinationPojos);
    modelMap.addAttribute("applicantData", userDataPojo );
    if (applicantDataPojo == null) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("Msg", "User is Not Found");
    }
    return "updateuser";
}
```

And 
updateuser.jsp

```
        <label>Country*</label>
        <form:select class="form-control"
         onChange="AjaxCallStateperma()" id="parmanentCountry" 
         path="parmanentCountry">
         <form:option value="${null}">Select</form:option>
         <form:options items="${countries}" itemLabel="countryName" 
         itemValue="countryId" />
         </form:select>


        <label>State*</label>
        <form:select class="form-control"
         onChange="ajaxcalldistrictperma()" id="parmanentState" 
         path="parmanentState">
        <form:option value="${null}">Select</form:option>
        </form:select>
```

and my ajax is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // business Address to list start
    function AjaxCallState() {
        var country = $('#businessCountry').val();
        console.log(country);
        $.ajax({
            url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/loadState",
            async : false,
            type : "GET",
            data : "state=" + country,

            contentType : "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                $('#businessState').empty();
                $('#businessState').append(
                        '<option value="null">Select State</option>');
                $.each(data, function(i, value) {
                    $('#businessState').append(
                            $('<option>').text(value.stateName).attr(
                                    'value', value.stateId))
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with myself.We should use IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expressions) function in javascript.